# Google Maps Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a page which has a map containing many markers and a list on the side of the marker titles. This example helped me get started. http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/pc7Uu/

I have images and descriptions relative to each marker location that I would like to display in the side list only when the associated marker is clicked.

Any ideas in how I could go about implementing this logic? Thanks.

Here is my HTML

```
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
     <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
     <img ng-src="{{marker.image}}" alt="\{\{album.album\}\} Cover Image" width="300px;" height="300px;">
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my angular

```
//Angular App Module and Controller
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope) {

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.51, 7.432),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false
}

$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

$scope.markers = [];

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
maxWidth: 200
});

var createMarker = function (info){

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
        title: info.location,
        image: info.img
    });
    marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
        infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
    });

    $scope.markers.push(marker);

}  

for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
    createMarker(cities[i]);
}

$scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
    e.preventDefault();
    google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
}

});
```

Here is my JSON

```
var cities = [
{
    location : 'Unguwar Rimi',
    desc : "<div id='hook' class='image'><img src=\"images/wells/KA KAF 001 Unguwar Rimi/IMG_4569.JPG\"><br><strong>Kaduna, Nigeria</strong><br>Village: Unguwar Rimi<br>Completed: 2011<br><p>'This borehole is a good blessing, our labor and stress is reduced.'</p></div>",
    img: "images/wells/KA KAF 001 Unguwar Rimi/IMG_4569.JPG",
    lat : 10.52,
    long : 7.43
},
{
    location : 'Gidan Bege Kadarko Kagoro',
    desc : "<div id='hook' class='image'><img src=\"images/wells/KA KAU 001 Gidon Bege Kadarko Kagoro/IMG_4556.JPG\"><br><strong>Kaduna, Nigeria</strong><br>Village: Unguwar Rimi<br>Completed: 2008<br><p>'God is great, the village no longer has a water problem and we never run short of water.'</p></div>",
    img: "images/wells/KA KAU 001 Gidon Bege Kadarko Kagoro/IMG_4556.JPG",
    lat : 10.53,
    long : 7.27
},
{
    location : 'ECWA Seminary Kagoro',
    desc : "<div id='hook' class='image'><img src=\"images/wells/KA KAU 002 ECWA Seminary Kagoro/IMG_8123.JPG\"><br><strong>Kaduna, Nigeria</strong><br>Village: ECWA Seminary Kagoro<br>Completed: 2008<br><p>'God is our Savior. He blessed us with this borehole which provides water to our staff and students'</p></div>",
    img: "images/wells/KA KAU 002 ECWA Seminary Kagoro/IMG_8123.JPG",
    lat : 9.69,
    long : 8.39
}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a scope variable to something in the click event.

In your controller:

```
     $scope.selectedMarker = {};
     // etc
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){

        infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
        $scope.selectedMarker = marker;
        $scope.$apply();
        infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
    });
```

On your view you can:

```
  <h1>{{selectedMarker.title}}</h1>
```

Here is a full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pc7Uu/194/

Also if you want to display HTML (marker's content) on the version of angular you've included (1.1.1) you will need to include ngSanitize.

http://jsfiddle.net/xVGP5/1/

Comment: No problem, there is an angular google map directive you might look into using.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map